# How to extract the object of interest from a background when there's low contrast?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, image-segmentation

I'm working on a project in which we require to extract the cans being transported by a conveyor belt. I develop an automatic threshold selection algorithm based on Kittler's approach which uses the histogram of the grayscale image to determine the optimum threshold to separate the object from the background (similar to Otsu's algorithm implemented in OpenCV).

Now, for the algorithm to be successful it requires proper contrast between the object being analyzed and the background, so I have had so trouble making it work with the images below. To enhance the contrast on the image I have tried different contrast stretching and adaptive equalization with poor results.

So, I would like to know any suggestions on how to improve the image contrast? Or if there's a different segmentation method that could work better on this images instead of thresholding? An important detail to consider is that the camera is working with a blue led light.

Half full conveyor belt:

[image: Half full conveyor belt]

Full conveyor belt:

[image: Full conveyor belt]

Comment: Try analyzing the image ina different color space (HSV, LAB, etc..)

Comment: Can you post the image in greyscale?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote some python code to start you off.

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
image = Image.open("TDP4f.jpg")
arr = np.asarray(image)
grey = np.mean(arr.astype(float)/255.0,axis=2)
grey = cv2.equalizeHist((255*grey).astype(np.uint8)).astype(float)/255.0
binary = cv2.adaptiveThreshold((255*grey).astype(np.uint8),255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,cv2.THRESH_BINARY,5,0.0)

#binary = cv2.morphologyEx(binary.astype(np.uint8),cv2.MORPH_ERODE,np.ones((3,3)),iterations=1)

# --- Adapted from https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/da/d53/tutorial_py_houghcircles.html
cimg=arr.copy()
R=20
err = 0.1
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(binary,cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,2,R,
                            param1=50,param2=30,minRadius=int(R-err*R),maxRadius=int(R+err*R))
circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
for i in circles[0,:]:
    # draw the outer circle
    cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(0,255,0),2)
    # draw the center of the circle
    cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),2,(0,0,255),3)
# ---

plt.subplot(1,2,1)
plt.imshow(binary,cmap='gray')
plt.subplot(1,2,2)
plt.imshow(cimg)
plt.show()
```

Result:

[image]

You can tweak the parameters to get a better fit.

Resources:

```
https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/da/d53/tutorial_py_houghcircles.html
https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d1b/tutorial_histogram_equalization.html
https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html
```